# Correct way to add PostCSS support to Vue cli 3

Tags: vue.js, postcss, vue-cli

How do we add PostCSS support to Vue cli 3 (I'm using beta 7)? Is there a plugin for it? Its not supported out of the box.

When I tried to import like this

`import './index.pcss'`

using the default cli generated project

```
./src/index.pcss
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .sofa {
|   font-family: "sofachrome", serif;
| }
 @ ./src/main.js 5:0-22
```

my postcssrc.js:

```
module.exports =
  {
    'plugins': {
      'autoprefixer': {},
      'postcss-smart-import': {},
      'postcss-custom-properties': {},
      'postcss-nested': {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/css.md#postcss) it is actually supported by default.

Comment: Well its not working in my case @yuriy636,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `.css` extension, not `.pcss`. If you must use `.pcss` you'll have to configure that in webpack. As for how to properly tap into that rule to do that I'd need to research a bit. Though, I think just using `.css` is a clear win.

Comment: Thanks guys! That helps

Comment: I does break the IDE webstorm if you post pcss into css

Answer (score 5):

PostCSS (as pointed out by Bill and Yuriy) works *by default*, but the Webpack loader is only configured for `.css` extensions. To modify it, update your `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('pcss')
      .use('postcss-loader')
      .tap(options =>
        merge(options, {
          sourceMap: false,
        })
      )
  }
}
```

Modify the example according to your needs.
Read more in [vue-cli docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md#modifying-loader-options)

Comment: Thanks guys! That helps

Comment: I just tried this but get  **INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  ReferenceError: merge is not defined**

Comment: @Nikos sorry for the long reply; the `merge` method should be imported from a utility package (either from lodash or any similar [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=merge) )